# Vision Cone. Visible vs BLACK, Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, mask

I've been trying to get my head around how to do a player vision like what is in Teleglitch (If the player can see the objects they're shown, otherwise it's black).

(gameplay from Teleglitch : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0OBXdEwawqI)

I am currently developing an turn-based strategy game where I would like this feature. Problem is that I actually have the Vision Cones already but I am not sure how I would go about doing this.

I've seen some guides around to do the vision cones, how do I actually apply the "darkness"?
I have a feeling that the best way would be a shader, but I can't seem to find what I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: There's a relatively cheap 2D volumetric lighting plugin in the Unity Asset Store that might help you. https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/3787

Answer (score 0):

In Teleglitch, it looks like they simply render black polygons over the shadow areas. Another approach in Unity is to use [depth masks](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=DepthMask). Unity 4.2 Pro also supports [stencil buffers](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/SL-Stencil.html) which are useful for masking effects.